# I have a vector with IDs with duplicates of rows in a data table. How do I return the rows that match the vector in order preserving duplicates

Tags: r, subset

The vector has duplicate IDs which I would like to preserve:

```
vector <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,5)
```

That is, it should return the first row 4 times, then the second row twice, the third row 3 times, etc.

Typically when doing this I use something like:

```
df2 <- subset(df1, ID %in% vector)
```

However, this only returns the unique elements, i.e. the 1st row once, the 2nd row once, the 3rd row once, etc.

Comment: `df1[vector,]` should work.

Comment: Well look at that! Thank you!

Comment: What if the vector corresponded to actual values of df$ID and not just the row numbers?

Comment: Can't say without a sample dataframe, but `df1[match(vector, df1$ID), ] ` should do it